# IntelliJ + jRebel - how to disable jRebel building a class upon CTRL+S?

Tags: intellij-idea, jrebel

I save frequently in ItelliJ and so each save triggers a jRebel build of that particular class which affects my IDE's performance. I would like to have a different shortcut for jRebel build but I can't seem to get IntelliJ not to trigger a build every time I click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

Would anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I disabled the "Enable incremental compilation on Save" option in my Eclipse Mode plugin for now to resolve this.

Comment: Don't use Eclipse Mode plug-in, it will cause performance problems.